# Suppressing Pipeline console output

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I am using waitFor{} function and in cases where it could be several minutes of waiting, there is an awful lot of console output during the wait period. Any thoughts on how to suppress some/all of it? Bad idea?

Comment: Would like to be able to suppress output from things like this as well (sleep, waitUntil)

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible. Could be patched to be quieter perhaps.